# Write Dirichlet Log Likelihood with DCP ruleset

Tags: cvxpy, convex-optimization

I would like to write the log likelihood of the [Dirichlet density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) as a [disciplined convex programming](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/disc_cvx_prog.html) (DCP) optimization problem with respect to the parameters of the Dirichlet distribution `alpha`. However, the log likelihood

```py
def dirichlet_log_likelihood(p, alpha):
  """Log of Dirichlet density.
  p: Numpy array of shape (K,) that sums to 1.
  alpha: Numpy array of shape (K, ) with positive elements.
  """
  L = np.log(scipy.special.gamma(alpha.sum()))
  L -= np.log(scipy.special.gamma(alpha)).sum()
  L += np.sum((alpha - 1) * np.log(p))
  return L
```

despite being concave in `alpha` is not formulated as DCP because it involves the difference of two concave functions `np.log(gamma(alpha.sum()))` and `np.log(gamma(alpha)).sum()`. I would like if possible, to formulate this function of `alpha` so that it follows the [DCP ruleset](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html), so that maximum-likelihood estimation of `alpha` can be performed with [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/).

Is this possible, and if so how might I do it?

Comment: Maybe visiting exercise 3.56 on page 124 in https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf is useful.

Comment: Thats definitely helpful, but I have already convinced myself that this function is concave (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710123/form-dirichlet-log-likelihood-with-dcp-ruleset)). Are there any ways of turning an argument/proof of convexity into a DCP formulation?

Comment: I doubt the gamma  function can be used in DCP.

Comment: There is an approximation to log gamma that can be used for cvxpy [provided in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/228#issuecomment-544281906).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, `np.log(gamma(alpha.sum()))` and `-np.log(gamma(alpha)).sum()` have different curvature, so you need to combine them as

```
np.log(gamma(alpha.sum()) / gamma(alpha).sum())
```

to have any chance of modelling them under the DCP ruleset. The combined expression above can be recognized as the logarithm of the multivariate beta function, and since the multivariate beta function can be written as a product of bivariate beta functions (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710123/form-dirichlet-log-density-with-dcp-ruleset)), you can expand the log-product to a sum-log expression where each term is of the form

```
np.log(beta(x,y))
```

and this is the convex atom you need in your DCP ruleset. What remains of you, to use it in practice, is to feed in an approximation of this atom into cvxpy. The `np.log(gamma(x))` approximation [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/228#issuecomment-544281906) will serve as a good starting point.

Please see [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710123/form-dirichlet-log-density-with-dcp-ruleset) for more details.